# How to get SMTP credentials from Google API PHP Client

Tags: php, api, smtp, gmail, credentials

I'm trying to get gmail SMTP credentials from google API after authentication. I've done the authentication part and I'm able to use the token in Google services but I could not find any method that gives me the SMTP Credentials in the Gmail Service class of the PHP Library. Is it possible or is there an alternative way of sending emails through SMTP on user's behalf without asking the user for authentication every time.

Answer (score 0):

Google does provide you an SMTP server via which you can send emails. You can use your Gmail login and password as credentials. Following are the server details,

```
SMTP Server : smtp.gmail.com
SMTP Username: Your full Gmail username (email address), for example youremail@gmail.com
SMTP Password: Your Gmail password.
SMTP Port: 587
```

Comment: I'm not trying to send emails through my own gmail account. I want my users to authenticate using google and use their credentials for sending emails. I just want their credentials after authentication. The rest is done and working properly.

Comment: Google will just not handover you the passwords of its users. You have to explicitly take the password from the user but can be a potential security risk as I guess you don't have a better security mechanism than Google.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to get user's credential through google authentication. it's not supported to get credential.

If you see the policy to get user' information, it's just about user's name and photo, birthday etc. not for credentials.

Comment: So what else can I do in order to send emails through user's SMTP anytime after authentication?